# reference to invalid character number: (Python ElementTree parse)

Tags: python, elementtree

I have xml file which has following content:

```
    <word>vegetation</word>
    <word>cover</word>
    <word>(&#x2;31%</word>
    <word>split_identifier ;</word>
    <word>Still</word>
    <word>and</word>
```

When I read the file using ElmentTree parse, it gives me error :

> xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: reference to invalid character
>   number

Its becuase of (&#x2 which is "~").

How can I take care of such issues. I am not sure how many other symbols i would get in future.

Comment: Are you sure that `&#x2;` is the tilde html code? I think `&#x126;` is the correct code: https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/tryit.asp?deci=126 (and try: https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/tryit.asp?deci=2).

Comment: Actually, its "~" in pdf which i convert into text(xml) using PDFbox and then I am parsing that XML using pythong library ElementTree and thats where it is causing me the issue. So, in the xML its is &#x2. I wont mind if I dont get correct parsing. but I want to get the file parsed without any error, as other content is important.

Comment: Can't you replace XML entities with code < 32 by spaces? I mean: fix the pdfBox text before passing it to elementTree.

Comment: sure. thats an option.But how would I do that. Is there any uniocde codec to do that?